# Characterising singular homology among a more general class of cosimplicial spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

> Is there a way to characterise (up to isomorphism) the simplicial spaces $F: \Delta \to \underline{\text{Top}}$ with $F( \underline{n}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ compact and $F(\underline{0})$ a point?
>   ${}$

If the above class is not too general, can - at least - the standard cosimplicial space, given by
$\Delta_n = \{(t_0, \dots, t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \: | \: t_i \geq 0, \sum t_i = 1 \} $
and the usual maps, be singled out in some way? (Or, if the class above is too general, may you suggest a more workable refinement?)

Comment: cross-listed: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150063/characterising-singular-homology-among-a-more-general-class-of-simplicial-spaces